# Using Google Fonts without API offline

Tags: php, jquery, css, json, fonts

I wanted to use Google Fonts without their API (try many fonts for my website). So, I downloaded a snapshot from here:
https://github.com/google/fonts and copied it to my web directory.

I can use ttf files if needed but the link provides a metadata.json file for each font with this structure:

```
    {
     "name": "Open Sans",
     "designer": "Steve Matteson",
     "license": "Apache2",
     "visibility": "External",
     "category": "Sans Serif",
     "size": 113987,
     "fonts": [
{
  "name": "Open Sans",
  "style": "normal",
  "weight": 300,
  "filename": "OpenSans-Light.ttf",
  "postScriptName": "OpenSans-Light",
  "fullName": "Open Sans Light",
  "copyright": "Digitized data copyright © 2010-2011, Google Corporation."
},
{
  "name": "Open Sans",
  "style": "italic",
  "weight": 300,
  "filename": "OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf",
  "postScriptName": "OpenSansLight-Italic",
  "fullName": "Open Sans Light Italic",
  "copyright": "Digitized data copyright © 2010-2011, Google Corporation."
},
{
  "name": "Open Sans",
  "style": "normal",
  "weight": 400,
  "filename": "OpenSans-Regular.ttf",
  "postScriptName": "OpenSans",
  "fullName": "Open Sans",
  "copyright": "Digitized data copyright © 2010-2011, Google Corporation."
},
{
  "name": "Open Sans",
  "style": "italic",
  "weight": 400,
  "filename": "OpenSans-Italic.ttf",
  "postScriptName": "OpenSans-Italic",
  "fullName": "Open Sans Italic",
  "copyright": "Digitized data copyright © 2010-2011, Google Corporation."
},
{
  "name": "Open Sans",
  "style": "normal",
  "weight": 600,
  "filename": "OpenSans-Semibold.ttf",
  "postScriptName": "OpenSans-Semibold",
  "fullName": "Open Sans Semibold",
  "copyright": "Digitized data copyright © 2011, Google Corporation."
},
{
  "name": "Open Sans",
  "style": "italic",
  "weight": 600,
  "filename": "OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ttf",
  "postScriptName": "OpenSans-SemiboldItalic",
  "fullName": "Open Sans Semibold Italic",
  "copyright": "Digitized data copyright © 2010-2011, Google Corporation."
},
{
  "name": "Open Sans",
  "style": "normal",
  "weight": 700,
  "filename": "OpenSans-Bold.ttf",
  "postScriptName": "OpenSans-Bold",
  "fullName": "Open Sans Bold",
  "copyright": "Digitized data copyright © 2010-2011, Google Corporation."
},
{
  "name": "Open Sans",
  "style": "italic",
  "weight": 700,
  "filename": "OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf",
  "postScriptName": "OpenSans-BoldItalic",
  "fullName": "Open Sans Bold Italic",
  "copyright": "Digitized data copyright © 2010-2011, Google Corporation."
},
{
  "name": "Open Sans",
  "style": "normal",
  "weight": 800,
  "filename": "OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf",
  "postScriptName": "OpenSans-Extrabold",
  "fullName": "Open Sans Extrabold",
  "copyright": "Digitized data copyright © 2011, Google Corporation."
},
{
  "name": "Open Sans",
  "style": "italic",
  "weight": 800,
  "filename": "OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf",
  "postScriptName": "OpenSans-ExtraboldItalic",
  "fullName": "Open Sans Extrabold Italic",
  "copyright": "Digitized data copyright © 2010-2011, Google Corporation."
}
],
  "subsets": [
"cyrillic",
"cyrillic-ext",
"devanagari",
"greek",
"greek-ext",
"latin",
"latin-ext",
"menu",
"vietnamese"
],
"dateAdded": "2011-02-02"
}
```

May I know how I can use this json file served for every font to get a proper css declaration.
For example, API provides the CSS when you see http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans after which I can use any type of Open Sans font I want.

So, how can I use this metadata json file to generate that css (which is generated by the API?

I am using PHP, Jquery, etc. for my project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.. I wrote my own code for this. I read json file using php depending on get request and then decoded json to get the contents and then will do the css.

You have to change

```
    <?php
if(isset($_GET["family"])&&isset($_GET["licence"]))
{
$family=$_GET["family"];
$licence=$_GET["licence"];
$family=strtolower($family);
$licence=strtolower($licence);
if($family==""||$licence=="")
{
    die("");
}

$dir="";
if($licence=="apache")
{
    $dir="apache";
}
else
if($licence=="ofl")
{
    $dir="ofl";
}

$path="Path to json file"; //have format like "/fonts/fonts-master/".$dir."/".$family."/METADATA.json";
if(file_exists($path))
{
    $contents=file_get_contents($path);
    $obj=json_decode($contents);
    echo $obj->{'fonts'}[0]->{'weight'}; 
    //var_dump(json_decode($contents));
}
else
{
    die("");
}
   }
//You can now use these json values to get the css
?>
```

I did not do this part till now but obviously you have to set headers as header(“Content-type: text/css”); when serving the css file